# Spectrum of $A + s N$ constant in $s$ when?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $A$, $N$ matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that the spectrum ( with multiplicities) of the matrix $A + s N$ does not depend on $s$.

I am trying to show that $A$, $N$ can be simultaneously reduced to an upper triangular form, with $N$ strictly upper triangular.

Notes:

The hypothesis is equivalent to " the characteristic polynomial of $A + s N$ does not depend on $s$ ".

It is easy to see that condition is equivalent to : for every $1\le m \le n$ the trace $\operatorname{tr} ( A + s N)^m$ is constant in $s$.  This implies right away that $\operatorname{tr} N^m = 0$ for all $1\le m \le N$, so $N$ is nilpotent.

It would be enough to show that $A$ and $N$ have a common eigenvector.  One could try to prove this: if $\det (A + s N) = 0$ for all $s$, then $A$, $N$ have a common zero eigenvector. That would in fact prove the result, so it might be a viable route.  (In fact not viable !, see below)

Any feedback would be appreciated!

$\bf{Added:}$ I forgot that $\det(A+s N) = 0$ for all $s$ does not imply that the kernels of $A$, $N$ intersect non-trivially. There may be the issue that the images of $A$, $N$ do not generate the whole space.

$\bf{Added:}$ The assertion is wrong, as showed by the counterexample of @just a user.

With Mathematica, I found some counterexample in size $3 \times 3$ as follows: take $A$ a Jordan cell of size $3$ ( the $\lambda$ will not matter).  Now find all those $N$ satisfying

$$\operatorname{tr}(N, A N, N^2, A^2 N, A N^2, N^3) = 0$$

Clearly any such $N$ is nilpotent. However, it may happen that $A$ and $N$ do not share an eigenvector. A generic solution of such $N$ is

$$N = \begin{pmatrix} q^2 r & q^2 s & r^3\\ - q^3 & - 2 q^2 r & q( - 3 r^2 + q s)\\0 & q^3 & q^2 r \end{pmatrix}$$

with unique eingenvector ( up to proportionality)
$$v = ( r^2 - q s, q r, - q^2)$$

However, $v$ is not an eigenvector of $A$. Hence, $A$, $N$ cannot be simultaneously brought to an upper triangular form.

$\bf{Added:}$ With the above $A$ ( for $\lambda= 0$) $N$, we have the kernels of $A$ do not intersect, the ranges of $A$ together span the full space, yet $a A + s N$ is nilpotent for all $a$, $s$.

Comment: for some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ why not define $B:=A-\lambda I$ then the spectrum of $B+s N$ is constant in $s$ and $\det\big(B+sN\big)=0$ and of course any upper triangularization of $B$ also upper triangularizes $A$

Comment: @user8675309: Please feel free to write an answer, that will make it clearer for all of us :-)

Comment: haha I was just giving a hint for the "it would be enough" section.  It looks a lot more challenging now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0  & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, N = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0  & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

then $$A+sN=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & s & 0 \\ 1 & 0  & s \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ $$\det(A+sN-\lambda I)=(-\lambda)^3$$

But $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is the unique eigenvector of $N$ (up to a scalar) which is not an eigenvector of $A$, hence $A$ and $N$ don't share a common eigenvector, they cannot be simultaneously upper triangulated.

Comment: Excellent, great counterexample, thanks a lot!!

Comment: This counterexample was first given by Helmut Wielandt in [*Lineare Scharen von Matrizen mit reellen Eigenwerten*](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01175657), Mathematische Zeitschrift 53, 219–225 (1950).

Comment: Thanks for the information. This isn't too hard to construct. It's easy to check that the statement holds for $n=1, 2$, and as for $n=3$, as $N$ is nilpotent, we may assume it's already upper triangular and work out some $A$ accordingly.